# Thread safety guarantees in boost::intrusive

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, thread-safety

Although this case is not explicitly mentioned in the Thread Safety paragraph of the documentation of `boost::intrusive`, I would like to know if I can consider `boost::intrusive::list::front()` safe when:

- there could be one writer calling `push_back()` on the list
- the list has always one element at least

The list is of auto-unlink type. My intuition tells me that there are no reasons why `front()` and `push_back()` are racy in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's absolutely a race condition.

> Several threads having read or write access to different instances is
>   safe as long as inserted objects are different.

The key here is *different instances*. You are reading and writing to the same instance concurrently, and the spec clearly does not guarantee it's safety.

The implementation *might* be OK. I think that intuitively, it probably would be. But, the specification clearly does not make any guarantee about this at all, and you have to assume race condition since it is not guaranteed.